# MobX and setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build exception

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

In several places of our app there are exceptions like this:

```
EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER_MOBX 
The following MobXCaughtException was thrown:
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
This Observer widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
process of building widgets.  A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
  Observer
The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
  Builder

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4292:11)
#1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4307:6)
#2      ObserverElementMixin.invalidate (package:flutter_mobx/src/observer_widget_mixin.dart:70:24)
#3      ReactionImpl._run (package:mobx/src/core/reaction.dart:119:22)
#4      ReactiveContext._runReactionsInternal (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:345:18)
#5      ReactiveContext.runReactions (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:319:5)
#6      ReactiveContext.endBatch (package:mobx/src/core/context.dart:149:7)
#7      ActionController.endAction (package:mobx/src/core/action.dart:107:9)
#8      _$CatalogState.changeCatalogIndex (package:my_app/catalog/state/catalog_state.g.dart:37:43)
#9      _CatalogViewState.initState (package:my_app/catalog/catalog_view.dart:277:19)
#10     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4765:58)
#11     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4601:5)
...     Normal element mounting (112 frames)
#123    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3569:14)
#124    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3327:18)
#125    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5705:32)
#126    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6246:17)
#127    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#128    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#129    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
#130    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#131    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:5)
#132    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#133    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#134    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#135    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4987:5)
#136    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:183:11)
#137    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#138    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6125:14)
#139    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#140    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#141    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
#142    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#143    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4832:5)
#144    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#145    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6125:14)
#146    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#147    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6125:14)
#148    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#149    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#150    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#151    StatelessElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4708:5)
#152    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#153    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#154    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#155    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4987:5)
#156    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3314:15)
#157    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4652:16)
#158    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4800:11)
#159    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4343:5)
#160    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2730:33)
#161    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:913:20)
#162    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:302:5)
#163    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1117:15)
#164    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1055:9)
#165    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:971:5)
#169    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:251:10)
#170    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:209:3)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
```

Sometimes it's possible to avoid such an error by deferring state modification with `SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback`. And I don't fond of such a solution, but at least no error. But there are places in code where this hack doesn't work.
I really want to understand how to deal with it without hacks. The problem is I couldn't provide a reproducible code, because I can't reproduce this behavior in a simple demo app. And I have no idea why.
`_CatalogViewState` looks like that:

```
class _CatalogViewState extends State<CatalogView> {
  PageController _pageController;
  TabController _tabController;

  ProductsState _productsState;
  FarmersState _farmersState;
  ToursState _toursState;
  DishesState _dishesState;
  CatalogState _catalogState;
  CategoriesState _categoriesState;
  FiltersState _filtersState;
  GeoState _geoState;

  int get _index() => _catalogState.catalogIndex;

  // ...
 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _productsState = Provider.of<ProductsState>(context, listen: false);
    _farmersState = Provider.of<FarmersState>(context, listen: false);
    _toursState = Provider.of<ToursState>(context, listen: false);
    _dishesState = Provider.of<DishesState>(context, listen: false);
    _catalogState = Provider.of<CatalogState>(context, listen: false);
    _categoriesState = Provider.of<CategoriesState>(context, listen: false);
    _filtersState = Provider.of<FiltersState>(context, listen: false);
    _geoState = Provider.of<GeoState>(context, listen: false);
    if (widget.defaultCategorySlug != null) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _initDefaultSelectedCategory());
    }
    _clearEmptyDishesCategories(); 
    _catalogState.changeCatalogIndex(widget.defaultIndex);
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _index);
    _pageController.addListener(_switchTabColor);
  }

  // ...
}
```

and `CatalogState` like that:

```
class CatalogState = _CatalogStateBase with _$CatalogState;

abstract class _CatalogStateBase with Store {
  @observable
  int catalogIndex = 0;

  @action
  void changeCatalogIndex(int index) {
    catalogIndex = index;
  }
}
```

The strange thing is the error doesn't throw when I just opening CatalogView, but it happens if I open the catalog view item, then on the item details page, I return to the catalog view page. Flutter creates a fresh new CatalogView in that case and an error constantly appears.

Somewhere found that I should change store only during the reaction. But in this case what reaction should I choose? Besides I need to run this code only once. I've tried autorun reaction, but it just breaks the code and nothing is working as it should.

If I can't mutate store in `initState` (despite of the fact that in most cases it works well) then where is the alternative place for it?

Also I've tried this:

```
autorun((_) => _catalogState.catalogIndex, (int index){
   _catalogState.changeCatalogIndex(widget.defaultIndex);
});
```

and this:

```
untracked(() {
  _catalogState.changeCatalogIndex(widget.defaultIndex);
});
```

but no luck(. It's strange that `untracked` fails, because untracked store changes should not start the invalidation process.

It feels like there are cases when initState is called during of a parent widget build phase. And that's why the error occuries.

Any help or idea on how to debug it and fix is appreciated.

Comment: this error came when you set the state of app during widget build,

Comment: The problem is not in your `initState` but in your `build` method. You need to check if you call setState or update providers/mobx state while building the view

Comment: I don't see anything in the build method. Besides if there was something it should not work at all, but in most cases, it works. Also if I comment `changeCatalogIndex` then no errors.

Answer (score 1):

This error happens when you try to trigger a rebuild while in `initState`. If you want to trigger a rebuild on init logic, you can wrap that rebuild trigger inside a `postFrameCallback`. In this case I believe the problem was with the `catalogState`.

```dart
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _productsState = Provider.of<ProductsState>(context, listen: false);
    _farmersState = Provider.of<FarmersState>(context, listen: false);
    _toursState = Provider.of<ToursState>(context, listen: false);
    _dishesState = Provider.of<DishesState>(context, listen: false);
    _catalogState = Provider.of<CatalogState>(context, listen: false);
    _categoriesState = Provider.of<CategoriesState>(context, listen: false);
    _filtersState = Provider.of<FiltersState>(context, listen: false);
    _geoState = Provider.of<GeoState>(context, listen: false);
    if (widget.defaultCategorySlug != null) {
      SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _initDefaultSelectedCategory());
    }
    _clearEmptyDishesCategories(); 
    // this triggers a rebuild 
    // _catalogState.changeCatalogIndex(widget.defaultIndex);
    // you can do this in the first frame after initial build
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => _catalogState.changeCatalogIndex(widget.defaultIndex));
    _pageController = PageController(initialPage: _index);
    _pageController.addListener(_switchTabColor);
  }
```

Comment: I've mentioned that `addPostFrameCallback` doesn't work here. Also, I want to get rid of `addPostFrameCallback` all over the code base. I need a clean and idiomatic solution.

Comment: @ChessMax did you get any solution?

Comment: @ShashankSrivastava I didn't find a good solution. Now using `addPostFrameCallback` as a workaround.